# storing massive number of colored images histogram using python and mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, opencv

I am using this function. the question is how to store the output?

```
def makehistogram(img_path1):
    base = cv2.imread(img_path1)
    base = cv2.resize(base,(360,480))
    basehsv = cv2.cvtColor(base,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    histbase = cv2.calcHist(basehsv,[0,1],None,[180,256],ranges=None)
    histbase1 = cv2.normalize(histbase,histbase,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
    return histbase1
```

Comment: If you're trying to store the output in MongoDB, try to use this package Pymongo a driver to help you interact with MongoDB https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/

Comment: That will effectively be a 180x256 Numpy array of floats you want to store, won't it? I am no expert on **mongodb** (or anything else much) but maybe you could use **arctic** https://github.com/manahl/arctic

Comment: I guess the question is how you plan to use the data once you have stored it. If you are using it for histogram matching, you'll want it accessible as numbers. If you plan to use it to plot spectral images, you could store it as a TIFF image.

Comment: Thank you all for replying, yes i have tried Pymongo and its working to insert the matrix as json on mongodb simply.